# SignalR with asp:repeater

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I have no idea how to use SignalR with asp:Repeaters. When clicking on a button in a repeater, i want the text related to that button to change.

I've tried this so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function clicked(item) {
           var $txtMessage = $(item).prev();
           $txtMessage.text(((parseFloat($txtMessage.text()) + parseFloat(0.01))).toFixed(2));
   }
</script>
```

and this is the HTML code

```
<div class="row">

    <asp:Repeater ID="repEndedView" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="RepEndedView_ItemDataBound" EnableViewState="false">
         <ItemTemplate>
             <div>
                <a id="aProductLink" runat="server">
                    <asp:Image ID="imgProduct" Width="100" Height="100" runat="server" /><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblProductTitle" runat="server"/><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblBidder" runat="server"/><br />
                </a>
             </div>
         </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

But I am not sure how to incorporate SignalR with this. That is, something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            var IWannaChat = $.connection.myChatHub;

            var $txtMessage = $(item).prev();

            $txtMessage.text((parseInt($txtMessage.text()) + parseInt(100)));

            IWannaChat.client.addMessage = function () {
                var $txtMessage = $(item).prev();
                $txtMessage.text((parseFloat(txtMessage.text()) + parseFloat(0.01)).toFixed(2));
            };

            $("#SendMessage").click(function () {
                var $txtMessage = $(item).prev();
                IWannaChat.server.send(txtMessage.val());
            });

            $.connection.hub.start();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: an ambiguous question!

Comment: when clicking on a button in a repeater, i want the text related to this button to change

Comment: Did you try to see if your server receives the input and if your client code is called via RPC call from server?

Comment: There is no button in your repeater code (unless its the link!), also what does `item` variable stand for ? you are using it repeatedly `$(item).prev();`!!

Comment: If you simply want to click on a button and some text change in the HTML, you don't actually need SignalR. Do you need also something to change in the server side? Can you elaborate a bit more on what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: Have you had a look at http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20?

Comment: do you mean to change text of another user ?